# IT wants me to change all significant text (names, emails) to image files to avoid malicious web crawlers?

Tags: web-crawler

IT wants me to change all significant text (names, emails) to image files to avoid malicious web crawlers. Our CEO and Founder get hit with a lot of spam. How can I avoid what he's suggesting? It sounds like a pain and quite frankly, I don't think it's a good solution. Are there alternatives I should present to him?

Comment: Upgrade his spam filter.

Comment: If he is receiving a lot of spam then it's too late, his email address is already in spam databases and the amount of spam received won't drop significantly by doing that, so that solution it's not going to help with the spam problem but will make difficult for real people contact him. For new email accounts maybe it could be useful generating the email links using obfuscated JS as web crawlers usually don't parse JS (or didn't parse, I not sure about the state of the art in email harvesting).

Comment: IT, like Pennywise the clown? ;) Anyhow, this may be not the right forum for this type of question. There are other software development forums that this could be appropriate for.

Comment: Also, my company, Forcepoint (fmr. Websense) creates sophisticated Security Software, Endpoint Protection and Filters that could potentially help your company. Sorry about the shameless plug.